# jquery $.get() does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, get-request

In my javascript I created different $.get() requests with different parameters to the same php file. The code is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var isValid = false;
      var isWarning = false;
//event handler for name input 
      $('#name').keyup(function(){
        var name = $(this).val();
        console.log($(this).val());
//request php validation for name
        $.get(
          "validation.php",
          {name: name},
          function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        );
      })
//request php validation for student id
      $('#studentid').keyup(function(){
        var studentid = $(this).val();
        console.log($(this).val());
        $.get(
          "validation.php",
           {studentid: studentid},
          function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        );
      });
//request php validation for program
      $('#program').keyup(function(){
        var program = $(this).val();
        console.log($(this).val());
        $.get(
          "validation.php",
          {program: program},
          function(data){
            console.log(data);
          }
        );
      });
});
```

The request made on #name input works fine and return json data from the php script but the requests made on the rest of the input fields are not executed. Somebody please tell me the problem here which is so confusing

Comment: what's the response or error for `#studentid` and `#program` ?

Comment: One request per `keyup` is overkill - imho. Only check the input if it hasn't changed for a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Your first `keyup` handler doesn't have a semicolon at the end. It should not matter in most cases (they're optional in any remotely recent JS implementation), but some older browsers might not like it (and since the rest of your code uses them, might as well).

Comment: There's no difference between each of the 3 ajax calls. Assuming the 3 inputs are the same type and do have values, therefore, the difference must be in the php, which you've not included.

Comment: @codekaizer There is no response for #studentid and #program, even no error warnings. It seems the request for #name has not reached its timeout but even when I comment out the first event-handler of #name it still not work.